# Error when trying to add typewriter animation to web page

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have 1 error and 1 question:
Error: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzy8Z.png)
If you see on the right side, the cursor has gone to the right side completely

Question:
How do I do that after the typewriter effect of "typeWriter1" is completed it starts effect of "typeWriter2"

I tried to use display: inline-block
It did work but it became very choppy it looked like it was coming from left side of border

```css
#introduction {
  font-size: 175%;
  color: #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Solitreo", sans-serif;
}


/* Typewriter effect */

.typeWriter .typeWriter1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="introduction">
  <div class="typeWriter">
    <h1 class="typeWriter1">I am Anay,</h1>
    <h1 class="typeWriter2">A programmer</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: give .typewriting display: inline-block; it's going at the end because it's a block level element.

Comment: It does work but the text becomes very choppy-choppy like its looking like that letters are just coming from the left of the border

Comment: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/ExvYWYK  or https://www.sitepoint.com/css-typewriter-effect/  check this or maybe it will help you.